# Cannot press buttons in my Flutter app until I press the Debug button in Dart DevTools while debugging

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I'm writing a Flutter app and recently (I'm using the web-enabled version of flutter) I have to press the Debug button in the DartDev tool at the start of each debugging session to enable a button to work.For example, I press F5 on my keyboard to start the debugging session using the Mac iPhone Simulator as shown next:

[image: button disabled]

I Command-Tab into the Dart DevTool that's automatically started in my browser when I stated the debugging session and press the little "debug" button:

[image: press the debug button]

Immediately in the Simulator, the "Sign In" button is enabled:

[image: button enabled]

This also happens when debugging on Android.

Any idea why this is? I can type into the text fields without pressing the debug button. I have no idea why the RaisedButton is disabled at the start. It might seem like a minor annoyance, but multiply it by the 100+ times a day you run the debugger during development and the frustration adds up.

Here is a main.dart file that reproduces this behavior:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Bleu Inventory",
      //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginPage(), //MainPage(),
      theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.white70),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  bool _isLoading = false;
  String message = 'Please login to continue.';

  final TextEditingController emailController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();
  FocusNode emailFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    emailController.text = '';
    passwordController.text = '';
    emailFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
    //     .copyWith(statusBarColor: Colors.transparent));
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: _isLoading
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ))
            : ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  headerSection(),
                  textSection(),
                  buttonSection(),
                  messageSection(),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  signIn(String email, pass) async {
    Map data = {'USER': email, 'PASSWORD': pass};
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      message = 'logged in successfully';
    });
  }

  Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      // width: double.infinity, // MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: emailController.text == "" || passwordController.text == ""
            ? null
            : () {
                // setState(() {
                _isLoading = true;
                // });
                signIn(emailController.text, passwordController.text);
              },
        elevation: 6.0,
        color: Colors.blue[800],
        child: Text("Sign In",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container messageSection() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 40.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: Text(
        message,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  Container textSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            focusNode: emailFocusNode,
            controller: emailController,
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.email, color: Colors.blue[800]),
              hintText: "User Name",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            obscureText: true,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.blue[800]),
              hintText: "Password",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[800])),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container headerSection() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50.0, 20.0, 10.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 30.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('My App Name',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[800],
                  fontSize: 32,
                  shadows: [
                    Shadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        blurRadius: 6,
                        offset: Offset.fromDirection(0))
                  ],
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the output of flutter -v doctor

```
~/flutter_workspace/debug_example 
   flutter -v doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel dev, v1.13.5, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G2022, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.13.5 at /Users/jdavies/development/flutter
    • Framework revision 41a911099b (7 days ago), 2019-12-19 13:48:02 -0800
    • Engine revision 0f90e6546b
    • Dart version 2.8.0 (build 2.8.0-dev.0.0 aa6709974d)


[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/jdavies/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.0)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.0, Build version 11A420a
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.5

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 42.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 191.8593
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_202-release-1483-b49-5587405)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.41.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.7.1

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max • A96AF9B1-AE6E-423E-B4C5-9ECD4E2D8DE3 • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-0
      (simulator)
    • Chrome            • chrome                               • web-javascript • Google Chrome 79.0.3945.88
    • Web Server        • web-server                           • web-javascript • Flutter Tools

• No issues found!
```

Many thanks to JacksonZ for his insight and help with this. Using his suggestions, I have refactored the code into the following working solution:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "Bleu Inventory",
      //debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: LoginPage(), //MainPage(),
      theme: ThemeData(accentColor: Colors.white70),
    );
  }
}

class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  /// Are we waiting on the login process?
  bool _isLoading = false;

  String message = 'Please login to continue.';
  static const _minUserNameLength = 5;
  static const _minPasswordLength = 8;

  /// This variable tells is if the name and password text fields were of a valid
  /// length (or not) before the current keystroke. This keeps us from calling
  /// setState() every time a keystroke is added beyond the minimum.
  bool wasNameAndPasswordValidBefore = false;

  final TextEditingController userNameController = new TextEditingController();
  final TextEditingController passwordController = new TextEditingController();
  FocusNode userNameFocusNode;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    userNameController.text = '';
    passwordController.text = '';
    userNameFocusNode = FocusNode();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        child: _isLoading
            ? Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
              ))
            : ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  headerSection(),
                  textSection(),
                  buttonSection(),
                  messageSection(),
                ],
              ),
      ),
    );
  }

  signIn(String userName, pass) async {
    // Map data = {'USER': userName, 'PASSWORD': pass};
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = false;
      message = 'logged in successfully';
    });
  }

  Container buttonSection() {
    return Container(
      // width: double.infinity, // MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
      height: 40.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: RaisedButton(
        onPressed: areNameAndPasswordSupplied() == false
            ? null
            : () {
                setState(() {
                  _isLoading = true;
                });
                signIn(userNameController.text, passwordController.text);
              },
        elevation: 6.0,
        color: Colors.blue[800],
        child: Text("Sign In",
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 18,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
      ),
    );
  }

  Container messageSection() {
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      height: 40.0,
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0),
      margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
      child: Text(
        message,
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.black,
          fontSize: 18,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
        textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      ),
    );
  }

  /// Make changes to the UI IFF the name and password are supplied and of
  /// valid lengths and they were NOT both of valid lengths on the last keystroke.
  ///
  bool areNameAndPasswordSupplied() {
    // Are both fields valid at this moment?
    bool fieldsValid = userNameController.text.length >= _minUserNameLength &&
        passwordController.text.length >= _minPasswordLength;
    if (fieldsValid ^ wasNameAndPasswordValidBefore) {
      // The state has changed
      setState(() {});
    }
    wasNameAndPasswordValidBefore = fieldsValid; // Update our state of validity
    return wasNameAndPasswordValidBefore;
  }

  Container textSection() {
    return Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 15.0, vertical: 20.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          TextFormField(
            autofocus: true,
            focusNode: userNameFocusNode,
            controller: userNameController,
            cursorColor: Colors.blue,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.face, color: Colors.blue[800]),
              hintText: "User Name",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey)),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            onChanged: (newText) {
              areNameAndPasswordSupplied();
            },
          ),
          SizedBox(height: 30.0),
          TextFormField(
            controller: passwordController,
            cursorColor: Colors.black,
            obscureText: true,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue[800]),
            decoration: InputDecoration(
              icon: Icon(Icons.lock, color: Colors.blue[800]),
              hintText: "Password",
              border: UnderlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.blue[800])),
              hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
            ),
            onChanged: (newText) {
              areNameAndPasswordSupplied();
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  Container headerSection() {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 50.0, 20.0, 10.0),
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20.0, vertical: 30.0),
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Text('My App Name',
              style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blue[800],
                  fontSize: 32,
                  shadows: [
                    Shadow(
                        color: Colors.black,
                        blurRadius: 6,
                        offset: Offset.fromDirection(0))
                  ],
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold)),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Add some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Button being disabled means the `onPressed` method of your `RaisedButton` is `null`. This happens when the app first evaluate your email and password controller. The reason why pressing debug will make it work is that pressing debug force the app the hot-reload and re-evaluate your `onPressed` method. Since now the value of email and password is no longer `null`, the `onPressed` is not `null` either, and it becomes available.

My suggestion is to, instead of evaluating your `onPressed` method in-place, use the `onChange` method of the `textField` (which is your email and password input) to check if email and password exist and do `setState` to set your handler `onPressed` from null to your real handler.

The root cause of your problem is that Flutter won't evaluate your condition unless you do a `setState`. However, you don't know when the input is going to change (as you are not using `onChange` in `textField`) it will never be re-evaluated (of course until you do a debug).

Comment: By the way, the `setState` around `_isLoading = true;` is likely needed. You might consider adding it back if you meant to show a loading screen while making the backend authentication API calls.

Comment: Wow, not only did you answer my question, you also educated me a bit more on Flutter! Your ideas worked perfectly. For my fellow Flutter noobs, I am posting the updated code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to move logic inside your function and that way you can always have an `onPressed` method it just won't do `isLoading` and `signIn` unless `email` and `password` are supplied.  I also added an empty `else` block to illustrate how always having a `onPressed` method allows you to do something if these fields are empty.  You can remove it if you just want to do nothing.

```
onPressed: () {
  if (emailController.text != '' && passwordController.text != '') {
    setState(() {
      _isLoading = true;
    });
    signIn(userNameController.text, passwordController.text);
  } else {
    // Handle empty email and password, or just do nothing
  }
}
```

I also created a DartPad [here](https://dartpad.dev/8dcca0ef3405616d62f62990aff8d102) with a working example.